# How can I get this array to populate with my Input Values?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to populate an array that I'm hoping is "dynamic", so that I can input as many entries into it as I need at runtime. However, the array, to which I presume the pointer `NthTeam` is pointing to, is not populating:

```
int* NthTeam = NULL;    

NthTeam = (int*)realloc(NthTeam,(playerCounter*STND_NO_GAMES)*sizeof(int));

// loops through each player's standard number of games
for (int i = 1; i <= STND_NO_GAMES; i++) {
    //input the score into the remalloced array
    cout << "Enter player " << playerCounter << "'s score " << i << ": ";
    cin >> inputValue;
    NthTeam[((playerCounter-1)*STND_NO_GAMES+(i-1)))] = SanityCheck(inputValue);
 }
```

However, when I use `cin >> NthTeam[(playerCounter - 1) * STND_NO_GAMES + (i - 1)]` in my code, it does work...the array populates.

I was led to believe from [this link](http://www.cse.unt.edu/~donr/courses/4410/dynamicArrays/dynamicArrays.html) that you could use NthTeam just as you would a regular array, but I don't think that's what's happening here. The reason I can't just use `cin` is because I'm supposed to be performing a validity check on the input before allowing it into the array.

I'm very lost Googling for answers; much of it is too complex for where I am now.

Comment: Hi, You tag the question as c, but the code seems like c++. please make it clear which one is it.

Comment: Why are you using realloc and not malloc?

Comment: you shouldn't be using `realloc` that's for re-allocating memory for a change in size. You should either use `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: This is in the middle of a `do...while` loop, I excerpted the code. `playerCounter` continually iterates.

Comment: `malloc` or `realloc` - you should not cast their return value - pointer vs integer.. read this http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Comment: Of course, in C++ you shouldn't really be using `malloc`, `realloc`, and the like at all. And I sincerely hope your class isn't teaching you to. You'd be much better off using standard containers such as `vector`.

Comment: You may want to show the loop you pulled this out of.  Your problem might be in regards to `playerCounter`.

Comment: Have you checked that `SanityCheck` is returning good values?  i.e. does it work if you do `NthTeam[...] = inputValue;`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are programming in C++, the standard library is there to help.  For instance: [std::vector](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33631-c-vector-tutorial/).  Here's a brain-dead modification, and be sure to `#include <vector>`:

```
std::vector<int> NthTeam;    

// loop through each player's standard number of games
// inputting the score into the vector

for (int i = 1; i <= STND_NO_GAMES; i++) {
    cout << "Enter player " << playerCounter << "'s score " << i << ": ";
    cin >> inputValue;
    NthTeam.push_back(SanityCheck(inputValue));
}
```

You do need to think about what will happen when invalid input is entered (like entering a score of "tomato").  Consider how this will affect the error status of `cin`, what it will do if you try to read another integer from it when the last attempt yielded an error, and what `inputValue` will be.

It may be the case that you still need a "SanityCheck"...but it may be able to take for granted that it only needs to check integers.